# How do I test ref via jest?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

During testing, an error occurs in ref FlatList. How can I fix this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You try to do as below:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent />);
wrapper.instance().flatListRef.scrollToIndex = jest.fn();
expect(wrapper.instance().flatListRef.scrollToIndex).toHaveBeenCalled();
```